# In python Django I want to execute two statements on if else that if email is taken show message if employee id is taken show message

Tags: python, django

I have a html registration form where  I am displaying if any username or email exists or not so if it exists then display username is taken and if email exists it will display email is taken but the problem is even if I give email in the email field in the html form it says username is taken but not email I tried elif statement it didn't worked the username is taken is working perfectly but not email.

If anyone knows please help

This is my views.py

```
def Register(request):
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            email = request.POST.get('email')
            password = request.POST.get('password')

        try:
            if User.objects.filter(username = username).first():
                messages.success(request, 'Username is taken.')
                return redirect('/register/')

            if User.objects.filter(email = email).first():
                messages.success(request, 'Email is taken.')
                return redirect('/register/')
            
            user_obj = User(username = username , email = email)
            user_obj.set_password(password)
            user_obj.save()
    
            profile_obj = Profile.objects.create(user = user_obj )
            profile_obj.save()
            return redirect('/login/')

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    return render(request , 'register.html')
```

Comment: What does .first return.  Is it valid for an email field

Comment: Are you supplying same username for email condition check?

Comment: just check this lines am am giving two conditions for email and username only 1st statement is working that is username if User.objects.filter(username = username).first():
                messages.success(request, 'Username is taken.')
                return redirect('/register/')

            if User.objects.filter(email = email).first():
                messages.success(request, 'Email is taken.')
                return redirect('/register/')

Comment: Yes both returns are different for username and email they are just return redirect  @irfan wani

Comment: Pls replace the condition if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists() and check.

Comment: I have replaced the thing is its working when i dont have the username statement that is if i write only the email statement its saying email not taken but thats what i dont want i want both the conditions should execute like if elif nested if else upon the given conditions one statement will be executed

Answer (score 0):

Since django already sets unique to username so likewise you can set email to be unique in model itself.

```
User._meta.get_field('email')._unique = True
```

Then you can create a form and check if its valid and if there's duplicate entry for username or email it will show that its already taken.

Comment: Where should i put this statement?

Comment: In models.py file

Comment: no actually my requirement is not this just check my code