# In Python Django I want to run both the statements on if else that is if email is taken show it or if username show it

Tags: python, django

I have a html form fill sign up page where I am displaying if any username or email exists or not so if it exists then display username is taken and if email exists it will display email is taken but the problem is even if I give email in the email field in the html form it says username is taken but not email I tried else if like statement it didn't worked the username is taken is working perfectly but not email. Here I meant both statements should run individually

If anyone knows please help

This is my views.py

```
def Register(request):
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            email = request.POST.get('email')
            password = request.POST.get('password')

        try:
            if User.objects.filter(username = username).first():
                messages.success(request, 'Username is taken.')
                return redirect('/register/')

            if User.objects.filter(email = email).first():
                messages.success(request, 'Email is taken.')
                return redirect('/register/')
            
            user_obj = User(username = username , email = email)
            user_obj.set_password(password)
            user_obj.save()
    
            profile_obj = Profile.objects.create(user = user_obj )
            profile_obj.save()
            return redirect('/login/')

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    return render(request , 'register.html')
```

Comment: This seems to be the _third_ time you have asked this same question today... (1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67732997/in-python-django-i-want-to-execute-two-statements-on-if-else-that-if-email-is-ta 2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67736247/in-python-django-i-want-to-run-two-statements-on-if-else-that-is-if-email-is-tak), you can simply [edit] your question if you want to add some clarification, etc. Don't post the same question again and again.

Comment: I was going to post an answer, but someone already posted essentially what I was going to post as an answer the second time you asked the question.

Comment: I am not getting any clue how to do it I all the things

Comment: Can you help me this question @ Abdul Aziz Barkat

Comment: @JamesRowling i tried to give you a very simple idea on where your problem is. check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you specify one if after another if. To get more familiar with code flow, maybe try running your code in http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit .

if you try something like this:

```
def x(y):
    if y > 5:
        return True
    if y > 10:
        return False

print(x(12))
```

it will never return False, because even if the number is bigger then 10, it will stop at the first if condition.